# Obtain AJAX returned object in PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax, raspberry-pi

I have a program which is running server script on raspberry pi (client which is also a server). I'm scanning a barcode which then executes few commands (including generating XML file). When I submit the form with the `'serial'` number, I want to be able to retrieve the filename (string) returned from AJAX ($_POST) method in server.php? `if (isset($_POST['filename'])` does not return the filename, how do I obtain filename with a single AJAX? and use it in PHP? I have no error messages, the $_POST['filename'] is empty. I tried separating the script into a different file and creating another AJAX calling that PHP script but it did not fully work and I wonder if there is a possibility to do it with a single AJAX and make PHP listen for the returned filename.

Or maybe is there a better way to obtain the filename of the external file than through client-side? (there is always single XML file waiting to be picked up).

**server.php**

```
<?php

$show_error = "";

if (isset($_POST['serial'])) {
    $serialnumber = $_POST['serial'];

    if ($serialnumber > 0) {

        if (isset($_POST['filename'])) {
            $filenamer = $_POST['filename'];
            echo $filenamer;
        } else {
            echo "no filename returned from ajax call";
        }

        $remote_file_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '/345.xml';  //FILENAME NEEDED
        $local_file = '345.xml';                                              //FILENAME NEEDED

        $copy = copy( $remote_file_url, $local_file );
}

?>

<html>
<body>

<form name="test" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="serial" id="serial" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function scan(serialnumber)
    {
        return $.ajax({
            url        : 'http://localhost/test.php',
            type       : 'POST',
            dataType   : 'json',
            data       : { serial_no : serialnumber},
            cache      : false,
            success    : function(data) {
                              var filename  = data[Object.keys(data)[1]];
                               console.log(filename);
                        }
            });                      
    };

    scan(<?php echo $serialnumber; ?>);

</script>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: text/json');

# Get the serial
$serial_no = $_POST['serial_no'];
$return['serial_no'] = $serial_no;

# Get the filename of the XML file
$filename = shell_exec('find /var/www/html/*.xml -printf "%f"');
$return['filename'] = $filename;

$return['scanpink'] = 1;
echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

Comment: What exactly is giving you problems? What error message(s) are you getting? What have you tried so far? These should all be addressed in your question

Comment: @WilliamPerron `if (isset($_POST['filename'])` does not return the filename, how do I obtain filename with a single AJAX? and use it in PHP? I have no error messages, the `$_POST['filename']` is empty. I tried separating the script into a different file and creating another AJAX calling that PHP script but it did not fully work and I wonder if there is a possibility to do it with a single AJAX and make PHP listen for the returned filename.

Comment: there is no element `filename` in the `data` element of the ajax call, so it makes sense that it does not exist in the `$_POST` variable. As an aside, you should probably add this information in your question

Comment: @WilliamPerron Thank you, I added the information. When I inspect the object on the client browser I can see that `filename` is returned and I access it with `data[Object.keys(data)[1]]` but I don't know how it can be passed back to PHP?

Comment: You don't have filename in php because your form does not have `filename` field. After receiveing `filename` from ajax query you can do another ajax request with serial & filename fields or the second solution use hidden field. After receiving data in ajax you cannout use them in php - You have to send it (`filename`) to php.

Comment: Thank you @TomaszW. your suggestion was the way to go. I was able to solve my problem but if you could post the answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @UZIERSKI Welcome and it's nice to hear that my suggestion helped you. I created the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you don't have filename in php because your form does not include `filename` field. After receiveing filename from ajax you can do another ajax request with serial & filename fields or the second solution is to use a hidden field. After receiving data in ajax you cannot use them in php - You have to send it `(filename)` to php.